# contenteditible is not showing border on hover

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to match the hover over the contenteditible section here: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

This is what I have: http://jsbin.com/ipoziw/edit#javascript,html,live

Why is my `<p>` tag not showing the border when you hover over it, like the section is in the first link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border you see on the demo is not default behavior, they've used this CSS:

```
[contenteditable]:hover:not(:focus) {
  outline: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

Just add it to your own CSS: http://jsbin.com/ipoziw/2

Comment: That's odd, as the example website specifically says "Any elements with the contenteditable attribute set will have a grey outline as you hover over."

Comment: Yes, but that statement is limited to the page in question because that's how they have it set up. It's just a misunderstanding, I can see why it was interpreted that way.